# Creating multi-page application with Vue CLI3.0, how to handle this error?

Tags: vue.js, web, error-handling, config, webstorm

I am a beginner of Vue and I am trying to build a multi-page web application with Vue for practice. But I am having this problem below:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/index/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' in '/home/Username/Web/wk_front_end/src/index/views'
```

Here is the file tree of my project, every file is generated by Vue because I only want to test the multi-page, so I think it wouldn't be a coding problem.

[image: The screenshot of WebStorm]

Here is what I did:

> I created a folder called the `index` under the `src` folder, I then move all the files and folders that originally under `src` to `index` because I wish the `components` and `assets` are only used in the corresponding page.

My `vue.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "src/index/main.js",
      template: "src/index/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      title: "Index Page"
    },
  }
}
```

When I try to run it, I got the error above on the chrome window. And actually, the error is:

[image: The screen shot of terminal]

I think it might be caused by missing of configurations, but I really cannot figure out what those other configurations I need.

Does anyone have similar problem before? Does anyone know how to solve it? Or, does anyone have some successful multi-page example that I could take a look?

Really thanks for the help.

Comment: Following question may occur: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476995/how-to-deal-with-this-error-when-creating-multi-page-application-with-vue-cli3-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `@` is a shortcut for the `src` folder. Which would mean your current path resolves to `src/components/HelloWorld.vue`.

You could try doing `@/index/components/HelloWorld.vue`, which should be the correct path.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks a lot.

Can you take a look with this error reporting, I am keeping having this bug after I added the second page:

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /home/Username/Web/wk_front_end/src/user/login/login.js
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.

Comment: More detailed question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476995/how-to-deal-with-this-error-when-creating-multi-page-application-with-vue-cli3-0, please take a look only if you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my sight you may be importing your Vue components incorrectly. If you want to make multi-page-app why don't you try [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) ? Maybe it's not the direct solution for your problem but it will help you to better manage your pages (routes) in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have figured this out. Yes, you are right. but I want to make this a config practice in order to have a better understanding for the vue.config.js.